Can Akka.Net actors be both producer and consumer?
we have an application that is written with akka v1.4 and now we are migrating to newer version (v1.5).
In new version AtleastOnceDeliveryActor is deprecated and we should use Akka.Delivery to send reliable messages between actors.
I want to know can we have an actor that is consumer and producer at the same time ?
In other word it should be register as an consumer and register as an producer ?
